# .net 7 MAUI HTTP request does not receive response

Tags: c#, .net, macos, maui

When posting http request with maui on mac I do not get the response.

Here is the app:

```
namespace vsfwefer;

using WeatherApp.Client.Services;
using WeatherApp.Client.Models;


public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    AccuWeatherService service;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        service = new AccuWeatherService();
    }

    private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        City[] cities = await service.GetLocations("Berlin");
        Console.WriteLine("Got: " + cities[0].LocalizedName);
    }
}
```

And here is the service:

```
using System.Text.Json;
using WeatherApp.Client.Models;

namespace WeatherApp.Client.Services
{
    internal class AccuWeatherService : IAccuWeatherService
    {
        private HttpClient client;

        private const string base_url = "http://dataservice.accuweather.com";

        private const string autocomplete_endpoint = "locations/v1/cities/autocomplete?apikey={0}&q={1}&language{2}";

        string api_key = "correctly";
        string language = "pl";

        public AccuWeatherService()
        {
        }


        public async Task<City[]> GetLocations(string locationName)
        {
            string uri = base_url + "/" + string.Format(autocomplete_endpoint, api_key, locationName, language);
            Console.WriteLine("Calling for cities: " + uri);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var r = await client.GetAsync(uri))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Got content : " + r.Content);
                    string json = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Got json for cities: " + json);
                    City[] cities = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<City[]>(json);
                    return cities;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I do not get any error. just info that thread started and I never get a response.
**It works fine with console application** .net on the same computer. Is it some kind of permission stuff?

Comment: You can try to make some breakpoints and see if it will get the data from the url.

Comment: Of course, It's the first thing that I did. Problem was another. I will post it here so others can find the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by allowing arbitrary loads in Info.plist file. It was purely config problem.

So I went to `Platforms -> MacCatalyst -> Info.Plist`

And added this key:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

So here is how it looks like now:
[image: solution]

Hope this helps!